# Fixed Point of RG Flow of $\phi^3$ theory in 6 dimensions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter, renormalization, partition-function, effective-field-theory

I was calculating RG Flow equations for $\phi^3$ theory in 6 dimensions. The partition function and lagrangian are given below,

$$Z = \int D\phi\ e^{-\int^{\Lambda} d^6x \mathcal{L}[\phi] }$$

$$\mathcal{L}[\phi]= \frac{(\nabla \phi)^2}{2} + \frac{m\phi^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda\phi^3}{6}$$

Separate in to fast and slow modes,
$$\phi^+ ; \Lambda>k> \frac{\Lambda}{b}$$
$$\phi^- ; k< \frac{\Lambda}{b}$$

I now carried out the Renormalisation Group procedure as outlined in Chapter 3 of [David Tong Statistical Field Theory Lecture Notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) and in Chapter 8 of [Condensed Matter Field Theory by Atland and Simmons](https://www.amazon.in/Condensed-Matter-Theory-Alexander-Altland/dp/0521769752)  to obtain the renormalised couplings. I considering the one-loop diagrams and after rescaling, I get the following equations,

$$m^{\prime} = b^2(m - \frac{\lambda^2(1-b^{-2})}{256 \pi^3} + \frac{m \lambda^{2}log(b)}{64 \pi^3}) \tag1$$

$$\lambda^{\prime}= (1+\frac{\epsilon log(b)}{2})(\lambda + \frac{\lambda^3 log(b)}{64 \pi^3})$$

Here, $\lambda^\prime $ and $m^\prime$ denote the renormalized couplings occuring in the effective action and they are measured in *units of inverse cut-off*. I have set $d=6-\epsilon$ and used regularisation. Setting $b=e^l$ and differentiating, I get the following beta-function relation,

$$\frac{dm}{dl} = \beta_{m}(m,\lambda) = 2m - \frac{\lambda^2}{64 \pi^3} + \frac{m \lambda^{2}}{32 \pi^3}   $$

$$\frac{d\lambda}{dl} = \beta_{\lambda}(m,\lambda)= \epsilon\frac{\lambda}{2} + \frac{3\lambda^3 }{32 \pi^3}$$

To find the fixed points, I set the beta functions to zero and find that $(m,\lambda)=(0,0)$ is the only fixed point. Does $\phi^3$ theory in 6 dimensions have any non-trivial fixed point?

I have the following questions:

1. Does this mean that there is no non-trivial fixed point for the flow in any order in epsilon or will I find a non-trivial fixed point at some higher order in epsilon?
2. We always use order epsilon calculations and one-loop calculations to get a feel for the flow diagram in coupling space. How are we sure that this gives the actual behaviour in all of coupling space? Since all the approximations are carried out near the gaussian fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

About the first question, I think there is no Wilson-Fisher-like fixed point for $\phi^3$ theory in 6-epsilon. If you look at the potential part which is $m^2 \phi^2+\lambda \phi^3$, there is no local minima other than $\phi=0$, therefore there is no symmetry breaking.

While for $\phi^4$ theory, the Wilson-Fisher fixed point is essentially the result of symmetry breaking, separating the symmetric and the symmetry broken phases.